# C# ListBox, show multiple columns

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I currently have two listboxes. One is bound to a SQL table of games. The table consists of a `game_ID`, `Name`, and `Type`. My listbox has a display member and value member set to `Name`. I want to be able to select a game and move the selected item to the second `ListBox` and display the `Name`. That part is working fine. The problem I am having is that when this is inserted into a different SQL table I want it to insert only the `Game_ID` (along with another sequential ID), not the `Name`.

The desired result would be to display only the game name in the second `ListBox` but still be able to use the `game_id`. If I have to I can display both the `game_id` and `Name` in both listboxes.

[image] [image]

the top listbox is a simple select query of the games table and the following code is used to move the items to the bottom listbox:

```
if (lstGames.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            lstSelGames.Items.Add(lstGames.SelectedValue);
        }
```

and to remove from the listbox:

```
if (lstSelGames.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            lstSelGames.Items.Remove(lstSelGames.SelectedItem);
        }
```

Comment: You need to show us the code which you used to load data and add items to `ComboBox`.

Comment: If you load data into `DataTable` and use data-binding to show data in `ComboBox`. Then you can easily cast the selected item of combo box to `DataRowView` and get other columns rather than display member.

Comment: @RezaAghaei - I have edited the post. I am not experienced with C# so I apologize if my explanation is not clear. I will look into and see if I can implement the solution from your second comment. thanks.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I was able to get the first listbox populated with the ID and the game columns using a data table. But now null exception error when trying to add it to the second listbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple class with `Id` and `Name` properties and add instances of this class to the second `ListBox` while setting `ListBox.DisplayMember` to `Name` the same way as in the first `ListBox`.

```
public class Game
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Add item like this:

```
listBox.Items.Add( new Game(){ Id = 1, Name = "Some name" } );
```

And later retrieve:

```
var game = (Game)listBox.Items[0];
```